# Virtualenv can't seem to find Flask "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv

I'm working through one of the tutorials on Google App Engine and am running into an odd issue while installing dependencies using the following command:

```
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

while in my virtualenv. As I understand it should simply be downloading the dependencies specified in requirements.txt, however I keep getting the error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==1.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask==1.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Now this is very confusing because according to Flask's website, the most recent version is exactly 1.0.2, so I can't imagine that is the problem. I'm not very familiar with installing dependencies this way, is there something I'm overlooking?

Note: this is what requirements.txt looks like:

```
Flask==1.0.2
Werkzeug<0.13.0,>=0.12.0
```

Comment: No I didn't, I thought the purpose of this command was to install Flask to the environment however it is specified in requirements.txt?

Comment: I actually got it directly from this Google App Engine for Python turotial I'm following: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env#deploying_your_application                                                                              Hence my confusion as to why it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Could you try running the same command appending -vvv to the options ? `pip install -vvv -t lib -r requirements.txt`. You'll get a log, that you can add to main post to debug it. It might be a problem of not connecting to the server (since it's on cloud, ports might not be opened or something), this command will help us verify it.

Comment: Empty list of versions (`(from versions: )`) suggests that you have a network problem (cannot connect to `PyPI.org`) or an SSL-related problem (Python and OpenSSL are too old and should be upgraded).

Comment: @codingduck you can try a little trick to print all available package versions: `pip install flask==giveMeAllVersions`, what does this give you?

Comment: Hey thanks for help everyone -- @phd you were correct I needed to update OpenSSL and Python, there's some issue with 2.7.11 and openSSL that seemed to be fixed by updating to more recent microversion

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me turned out to be updating python and running

> pip install urllib3[secure]

as there seemed to be some issue with certificate authentication packages i.e. SSL